# overridden in Symfony 2 error customization?

Tags: symfony, error-handling, twig

I am working on error pages in symfony2 but I am not successful in override this template.

Can any one describe it How I can override all exception pages. I want three pages error.html.twig , 403.html.twig, 404.html.twig

I do this way:

first create file in this position:

```
app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception

app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/layout.html.twig
```

I put all twig exceptions file in Exception folder and write some custom code.

But I am some time success and some time got blank pages.

And this page is working in dev env but in prod env not show.

I want when error then error page , if 404 then 404 page error, if forbidden then 403 page.

Any one describe me or tell me how I can do this.

If write some code It's good for me ?

In other think I am all problem handle through RedirectExceptionListner service but I do not do this because this is redirect to error pages.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide your custom code for Exceptions? Did you run `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug`? What are the names of the files you created in Exception folder?

Comment: 404.html.twig,  403.html.twig, exception.html.twig

Answer (score 0):

Just create error + number of error + .hmlt.twig in app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception.

For the 404, the file would be error404.html.twig.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps to override error pages.

First of all: Follow tutorial on this page: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html. In app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception create file error.html.twig. You can also create error404.html.twig and other error pages. Content of the file is your decision.

Second step is to add assetic in your config.yml

```
assetic:
    bundles: ['TwigBundle']
```

Without that you will get blank pages.

And of course, don't forget to clear the cache and reinstall assetics:

```
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

How to know which error twig will be rendered? For me, the best solution is to create method in controller like:

```
function findQuestionOr404($questionId)
    {
        $survey = $this
            ->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('MyGreatBundle:Question')
            ->find($questionId)
        ;

        if (!$survey) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException());
        }

        return $survey;
    }
```

And then in action:

```
public function someAction()
    {
        $queston = $this->findQuestionOr404($id);
        //...
    }
```

This will throw 404 error (if there is no survey with particullar $id) and show error404.html.twig. Of course, you're free to throw any Exception class in your controller.

Comment: Thanks to every one for answer and comment. Then I can got this page through this throw new \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException();   but How I now this which error file get ? because exception are many type ? then we create many type error pages ?

Comment: I don't know If I understand you correctly, so I will try to add additional informations in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Ya. you are right .I want to show through exception class. My doubt is If I will create error file in TwigBundle folder and use any throw Exception class then How he get particular twig file.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Controller Show Action workes only after route url like www.symfony.com/about/hwsfhsbfh but In www.symfony.com/hfhdf not work show blank page on prod env and NOTHTTPFOUND Exception found in dev env , How can handle this ?